# Coding navigation buttons using vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, button, navigation

My main goal is to code navigation buttons to control records of a **vb.net** project connected with Microsoft Access Database. The four buttons included are First record, Last record, Next record and Previous record. The errors showing say "ShowData" and "CurrentRow" are not declared.

[image]

CurrentRow shows the following error correction options:

[image]

ShowData shows the following error correction options:

[image]

```
 'to navigate to first record
Private Sub btn_first_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_first.Click
    CurrentRow = 0
    ShowData(CurrentRow)

End Sub
'to navigate to last record
Private Sub btn_last_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_last.Click
    CurrentRow = Dst.Tables("Purchases_file").Rows.Count - 1
    ShowData(CurrentRow)

End Sub
'to navigate to previous record
Private Sub btn_previous_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_previous.Click
    If CurrentRow <> 0 Then
        CurrentRow -= 1
        ShowData(CurrentRow)
    Else
        MsgBox("First record is reached!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End If
End Sub
'to navigate to next record
Private Sub btn_next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_next.Click
    If CurrentRow = Dst.Tables("Purchases_file").Rows.Count - 1 Then
        MsgBox("Last record is reached!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else
        CurrentRow += 1
        ShowData(CurrentRow)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into `BindingSource` and `BindingNavigator`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you get you did not declare CurrentRow before using it in the methods. Put

```
Private CurrentRow as Integer
```

in your class. ShowData calls the method to retrieve the data from the database. It should be something like this:

```
Private Sub ShowData(byval row as integer)
'code to get the data in the database
End Function
```

If the variable and method exist in another class of the project you need to reference them via their class. For example:

```
ClassName.CurrentRow
ClassName.ShowData(CurrentRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Roasters table has field names of Name, City, and Zip. They are bond to labels on the `BindingNavigator` form and also a `DataGridView`. The `BindingNavigator` provides the buttons you describe.

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class BindingNavigator

```
Dim WithEvents bindSrc As New BindingSource

Private Sub BindingNavigator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = LoadData1()
    bindSrc.DataSource = dt
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindSrc
    lblItem.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bindSrc, "Name"))
    lblDescription.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bindSrc, "City"))
    lblPrice.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bindSrc, "Zip"))
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bindSrc
End Sub

Private Function LoadData1() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Top 10 * From Roasters;", conn)
        conn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

End Class